# How to refactor the initial piece of code to get the target (example from R.C.Martin's Clean Code)

Tags: java, refactoring

I'm reading R.C. Martin's "Clean Code" right now and I'm trying to get the hang of clean refactoring by trying to go from initial code to target, especially where the author doesn't explain the steps. In Chapter 17 the author has this example on the ugliness of boolean arguments:

```
public int calculateWeeklyPay(boolean overtime) {
 int tenthRate = getTenthRate();
 int tenthsWorked = getTenthsWorked();
 int straightTime = Math.min(400, tenthsWorked);
 int overTime = Math.max(0, tenthsWorked - straightTime);
 int straightPay = straightTime * tenthRate;
 double overtimeRate = overtime ? 1.5 : 1.0 * tenthRate;
 int overtimePay = (int)Math.round(overTime*overtimeRate);
 return straightPay + overtimePay;
 }
```

turning it to this:

```
public int straightPay() {
 return getTenthsWorked() * getTenthRate();
 }
 public int overTimePay() {
 int overTimeTenths = Math.max(0, getTenthsWorked() - 400);
 int overTimePay = overTimeBonus(overTimeTenths);
 return straightPay() + overTimePay;
 }
 private int overTimeBonus(int overTimeTenths) {
 double bonus = 0.5 * getTenthRate() * overTimeTenths;
 return (int) Math.round(bonus);
 }
```

I successfully (i hope) found the steps on everything but the overtimePay: I can't see why this (I simply took the corresponding line and started substituting the variables):

```
overtimePay = round(max(0, tenthsWorked - min(400, tenthsWorked))*overtimeRate);
```

can be turned into this:

```
overtimePay = round(0.5 * tenthRate * max(0, tenthsWorked - 400));
```

Also, I found that max(0, tenthsWorked - min(400, tenthsWorked)) is the same as max(0, tenthsWorked - 400). then, substituting the initioal max we get:
This:

```
overtimePay = round(max(0, tenthsWorked - 400)*overtimeRate);
```

should be turned into this:

```
overtimePay = round(0.5 * tenthRate * max(0, tenthsWorked - 400));
```

if overtimeRate is as given:

```
 double overtimeRate = overtime ? 1.5 : 1.0 * tenthRate;
```

Also, the multiply operator has higher precedence than the ternary, so it means the tenthRate gets multiplied only in the false condition and in the true it gives only 1.5 not multiplied by anything.
Please, could you point how to finish this refactoring?

Comment: "tenthRate gets multiplied only in the false condition" Indeed. Looks like a mistake. It should be `(overtime ? 1.5 : 1.0) * tenthRate`. Maybe the point could be made that this code is deliberately bad/broken... But I think it is the example which is bad. Uncle Bob is completely overrated as a programmer. His real talent is being good at self-promotion and marketing. I'm sure he's a nice guy but still.

Comment: Thank you!!! then the last point, why is 0.5 there in the new function?